# iOS 12 - app is not launching

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode10, ios12

iOS app is not launching on iOS 12. I have updated the system to "MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4(17E199)" and try running the project from "Xcode Version 10.0 beta 2(10L177m)” to "iPhone (iOS 12)". It didn’t work

I tried creating a sample project and tried with different
profiles.that also didn’t work.

Main Function itself is not getting called.Tried almost all the google suggestions.Tried installing Xcode 9.4 build in iOS 12,But same result.
its working fine in all other iOS versions and even in iOS 12 simulators.

[image: Xcode 10 beta - app not launching error]

Comment: Have Tried all those answers.Nothing worked for me. Xcode 9 build also not launching in iOS 12